# Resume from suspend - all programs are closed 12.04

Tags: 12.04, suspend, macbook-pro

I'm using a Macbook Pro 6,1 and have jumped through a few hoops to get to where I am.  I finally have a working system, but there's one thing I haven't been able to find a solution on.  When I close my lid on my Macbook it goes to suspend mode.  When I open my Macbook again it wakes and goes back to my desktop.  Only problem is it won't load the windows I previously had open.  It's as if I logged out instead of my computer going into suspend.  Is there any way to get my programs not to close when I close my laptop?  I have the latest Nvidia drivers installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found an answer to my own question.  The solution is the same one listed on here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2150687

Create the file /etc/acpi/local/lid.sh.post if it's not already created.  You may have to make the 'local' folder.  Add the following to the file:

```
#!/bin/bash
grep -q closed /proc/acpi/button/lid/*/state
if [ $? = 0 ]
then
/usr/sbin/pm-suspend
fi
```

Then make this file executable.  Everything works for me now... at least it has so far.